# How to make Safari remember zoom level per site?

Tags: safari, safari-extensions, zoom

Safari's default font size is not large enough for my eyes so I have to press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> for a while on every website I visit. I could've used CSS to [set the default zoom level in Safari](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1618/how-can-i-set-a-default-zoom-level-in-safari) but I want different zoom levels for Twitter, Facebook, StackOverflow, etc.

Is there an extension or other way available to make Safari remember **per-site** zoom level settings?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes,

There is an extension for this called [ZoomBySite](http://www.cerimorgan.com/products/zoombysite/). Here is a description of the software from it's website:

> ZoomBySite is a Safari Extension that will automatically zoom each
>   site to the zoom level of your last visit to the site. A site is
>   defined by a unique domain name (so www.apple.com is considered
>   different from store.apple.com and each could have its own unique zoom
>   level).
>
> It does this by intercepting the Zoom In and Zoom Out keyboard
>   shortcuts [...]. It zooms the page in or out by
>   the desired amount (see the Preferences section below) and also stores
>   the zoom level for the site. As each page loads, it checks to see if
>   there is a stored zoom level and sets it again for the current
>   viewing. If you change the zoom level of a site, any other tabs or
>   windows that are open to that site will also change their zoom level.

Comment: For some reason, it didn't work for me the first few launches but eventually it started hooking keyboard shortcuts, as promised. Amazing. Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't work.

Comment: Works for me. The built-in zoom kb shortcuts work well with this extension.

Comment: I take back my words: it works but constantly forgets zoom for tabs; also, zoom levels between individual tabs interfere with zoom levels in other tabs—in short: too buggy to be useful at this time (at least on my MBP)

Answer (score 6):

The [Quickstyle Safari Extension](http://canisbos.com/quickstyle) has served this purpose well for me.

In particular it allows changing **only the font size** or virtually any other very detailed change.

Click the toolbar icon (or use the keyboard shortcut) and select the element on the page that you'd like to apply changes to (*or* any element) to bring up the editor pre-filled with a rule that will apply to whatever you selected.

[image: screenshot1]

If you want to apply very generally simply rename the rule to `body`.

If you'd like to double the font size you would enter:

```
font-size: 200% !important;
```

The site should re-render as soon as you've saved the rule.

Comment: Quickstyle also remembers the zoom setting like ZoomBySite