# Making fonts larger in apps under Lion

Tags: macos, zoom, resolution

While there is [no system-wide way to make all fonts larger](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27863/is-there-a-way-to-make-all-fonts-larger-on-the-macbook-air-13-or-11) under Lion without leaving native resolution, many individual programs do have a way to make text and various elements larger on the screen. Unfortunately, this varies from one program to the next.

If the goal is to make text appear larger in all programs, can we put together a guide to zooming in the various apps in Lion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Safari

#### For Single Page

Press <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd> to **increase text size** on the page.
Swipe in or double-tap with two fingers to **zoom into** a page (iOS-like).

Note that text zooming and page zooming are not quite compatible and may cause odd effects when combined so you should stick with either.

#### For All Pages

To make Safari “remember” your text zoom setting, [use a custom stylesheet](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1618/how-can-i-set-a-default-zoom-level-in-safari/1620#1620):

> 1) Create a file named defaultzoom.css (or any name you like, just **make sure it has a css extension**.)
>
> 2) Copy and paste in the following:
>
> ```
>     body {  
>       zoom: 130%;  
>     }
> ```
>
> change 130 to whatever number suits you. `>100` means **zoom in**, `<100` means **zoom out**. Don't forget the % percent sign!
>
> 3) In safari, go to `Preferences > Advanced`. Under style sheet, select Other... and point to the file you created.
>
> 4) You may need to restart safari for the change to take effect.

#### For Certain Websites

Personally, I prefer [keeping text zoom level per site](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24458/how-to-make-safari-remember-zoom-level-per-site/25532#25532) with [ZoomBySite extension](http://www.cerimorgan.com/products/zoombysite/) by [Ceri Morgan](http://www.cerimorgan.com/about_ceri/).
It overrides the keyboard shortcuts and remembers the last text zoom level for domain.

Answer (score 4):

### Google Chrome

#### Its own UI, not web pages

The following settings in [TinkerTool](http://www.bresink.com/osx/TinkerTool.html) affect the following pieces of Chrome's own UI:

- Chrome address bar, i.e. URL:  **System** in TinkerTool (default font: Lucida Grande; largest size possible is **16 pt**; larger sizes are truncated)
- titles of tabs:  **Help tags** (default font: Lucida Grande; largest size possible is **13 pt**; larger sizes are truncated. Bold is ignored, it's always Regular)
- Chrome's ex-Wrench menu (top right corner): **Messages** (default font: Lucida Grande; upper limit is something like **24 pt**, further increasing the number has no effect)

#### Web page content

- Default zoom: Wrench > Settings (<kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>,</kbd>) > Show advanced settings > Web content > {Font size, Page zoom}. Both also affect how Settings page is zoomed.
- For a particular site: <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd> / <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>-</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

### Sublime Text 2

Press <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>,</kbd> to open user preferences file, then set `font_size` to the desired value:

```
{
    "font_size": 18
}
```

[image: Sublime Text 2]

Answer (score 2):

### Reeder

Press <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>,</kbd> to open the Preferences and tweak the **Article Font** from **Reading** tab:

[image: Reeder Article Font]

Answer (score 2):

### Twitter

Just open the preferences (<kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>,</kbd>) and change **Font size**.

[image: Twitter Font size]

Answer (score 2):

### iTunes

Open the preferences (<kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>,</kbd>).

You can select larger or smaller font size for sources and track list.
There is no way of selecting one for the browser columns though.

[image: iTunes preferences]

Answer (score 0):

### iCal

In the **View** menu, select **Make Text Larger** or press <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd>:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Finder

Open a Finder window. Press<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>. Select a font size. Click on **Use as Defaults**

[image]

Comment: Just a note on formatting: I think **Use as Defaults** looks far better on this website than `Use as Defaults`.

Comment: I prefer `Use as defaults`, but for consistency, I'll change on this one.